# symfony android add to homescreen

Tags: php, android, symfony, manifest

I followed the guide [Android to homescreen](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen).

In a pure html file, it's working.
But I don't get it to work in a symfony php project.
I have the following link in my base.html.twig:

```
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/manifest.json') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

manifest.json is in the correct place.

The following code is my manifest.json:

```
{
        "name": "Ubuntu",
      "icons": [
        {
          "src": "ubuntu36.png",
          "sizes": "36x36",
          "type": "image/png",
          "density": "0.75"
        },
        {
          "src": "ubuntu48.png",
          "sizes": "48x48",
          "type": "image/png",
          "density": "1.0"
        },
        {
          "src": "ubuntu72.png",
          "sizes": "72x72",
          "type": "image/png",
          "density": "1.5"
        },
        {
          "src": "ubuntu96.png",
          "sizes": "96x96",
          "type": "image/png",
          "density": "2.0"
        },
        {
          "src": "ubuntu144.png",
          "sizes": "144x144",
          "type": "image/png",
          "density": "3.0"
        },
        {
          "src": "ubuntu192.png",
          "sizes": "192x192",
          "type": "image/png",
          "density": "4.0"
        }
      ],
      "start_url": "app.php",
      "display": "standalone",
      "orientation": "portrait"
    }
```

Could the problem be with the start url?
What should be the "start_url" in a symfony project?
Anyone an idea on how to debug this?

Thanks,

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

According to [app manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest):

> If given as a relative URL, the base URL will be the URL of the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

First you should have

```
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/manifest.json') }}" rel="manifest"/>
```

instead of

```
<link href="{{ asset('assets/vendor/manifest.json') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then yes the front controller for a Symfony app is `app.php` but if you need to debug you should rather call `app_dev.php` and make sure you're layout has a `body` tag or else the profiler won't be rendered.

Comment: This does not change anything, I've changed it to manifest and the start_url app_dev.php and testing it invoking app_dev.php, it doesn't work. My html is correct but it's not showing the ubuntu picture. I'm not sure where to put the 'png'?